Adding a condition to a MAP formula
Now the formula looks for the dash sign in column A and outputs the 4th and 6th cell after it (the formula itself is in cell G1). It is necessary that if the word “OT” is found (as in row 30 and 108), the formula would output rows 6 and 8 in addition to the first condition.
MAP(FILTER(row(A:A), A:A = "–"), LAMBDA(_r, {index(A:A, _r + 4), index(A:A, _r + 6)}))

I have made a sample of what should get next to it, the places that need to be fixed highlighted in yellow
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13bmHZYMBtRYjT0lEuhq6GU_0ezXPNrIu47TDTbfl8kk/edit?gid=1601673558#gid=1601673558

Now the formula looks for the dash sign in column A... It appears that you already have a formula. The description of the problem is unclear and users shouldn't be required to open your spreadsheet in order to better understand the question. Would you please edit the question to explain your scenario; include data so that users can understand the problem; and include an example of a successful outcome. So far as the spreadsheet is concerned, the current outcome and the expected outcome are confusing (values seem to have been transposed); would you please make this more clear.

Here's something you can try. I changed your lambda helper function to reduce instead of map, using vstack:
=let(z,tocol(,1),range,(FILTER(row(A:A), A:A = "–")),REDUCE(z,range,LAMBDA(a,c,vstack(a,if(index(A:A, c + 4)<>"OT",{index(A:A, c + 4), index(A:A, c + 6)},{index(A:A, c + 6), index(A:A, c + 8)})))))

